# How to prove that $(A\cup B) \cap C \subseteq A\cup (B\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove: 
$(A\cup B) \cap C \subseteq A\cup (B\cap C)$

How could I go about proving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $x \in (A\cup B) \cap C$. Then $x\in C$ and $x\in A\cup B$.

Either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If it is in $A$ then it is in $A\cup (B\cap C)$. 
If it is in $B$ then it is in $B\cap C$, and we are done.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to rewrite it as
$$ [(x\in A \lor x\in B)\land x\in C] \Rightarrow [x \in A \lor (x\in B \land x\in C)]$$
and to verify that $[(p\lor q)\land r] \Rightarrow [p\lor (q\land r)]$ is a tautology.

Another way is using Venn diagrams. (See a little don's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36672/) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).)

Another possibility is use some facts you've already learned, like: $A\cap C\subseteq A$ implies $(A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)\subseteq A\cup (B\cap C)$ and $(A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$.

Answer (score 4):

Label each of the seven possible sections.

[image]

Determine which of those are in (A ∪ B) ∩ C, then which are in A ∪ (B ∩ C).

Every section on the list for (A ∪ B) ∩ C should be on the list for A ∪ (B ∩ C).